# Listing records owned by the same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations, relation

I have a simple Rails 3 application that has a number of models. A simple overview of the models I'm having trouble with is:

**client model**

```
has_many :animals
```

**animal model**

```
belongs_to :client
```

What I would to be able to do is show a list of other animals that are owned by the same client.

Something like this:

```
<% @client.animals.each do |animal| %>
  <%= animal.AnimalName %>
<% end %>
```

As this is within the Animal controller, my example code won't work. Any pointers would be appreciated.

**Update**

To clarify, if I have the following records:

```
Danny (Client)
Cat (animal owned by Danny)
Dog (animal owned by Danny)
Rabbit (animal owned by Danny)
```

and I then went to the show view of the Dog's record, I would like a list that would show all animals that Danny owned. E.g.

```
Cat
Dog
Rabbit
```

Ideally excluding the currently viewed animal (in this case dog).

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<% @client.animals.each do |client| %>
  <%= @client.animal.AnimalName %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *other* animals? Other than what? `@client.animals` should hold ALL the animals this client owns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you have `@animal` and want to show all the animals owned by the owner of `@animal`. This can be done like this:

```
<% @animal.client.animals.each do |animal| %>
  <%= animal.AnimalName %>
<% end %>
```

---

Update:

You can just add a `.where` onto `@animal.client.animals`:

```
@animal.client.animals.where('id != ?', @animal.id).each ...
```

It's not such a good idea to do this in a view. So I would add an instance method to my Animal model:

```
def other_animals_with_same_owner
  client.animals.where('id != ?', id)
end
```

With this you can do:

```
@animal.other_animals_with_same_owner.each ...
```

Comment: Ahh, I was trying the reverse '@client.animal' for some reason. Is there a standard way of omitting the current animal from the list?